# Restoring SSRS / PowerBI Reporting Server encryption key using Powershell

Tags: powershell, reporting-services, powerbi, sql-server-2016

I have the following Powershell code to restore an Encryption key on a Power BI Report Server instance:

```
$encKeyPath = "C:\Test\enc.snk"
$encKeyPass = Read-Host 'Enter password for key:' -AsSecureString
Restore-RsEncryptionKey -ComputerName "localhost" -Password $encKeyPass -KeyPath $encKeyPath -ReportServerInstance PBIRS -ReportServerVersion SQLServer2016
```

When I run this I get the error:

```
Get-WmiObject : Invalid namespace "root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ReportServer\RS_PBIRS\v13\Admin"
At C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\ReportingServicesTools\ReportingServicesTools\Functions\Utilities\New-Rs
ConfigurationSettingObject.ps1:100 char:19
+     $wmiObjects = Get-WmiObject @getWmiObjectParameters
+                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

I have tried also tried with the `-ReportServerInstance` and `-ReportServerVersion` parameters but get the same error message. I have also tried my local computer name for the `-ComputerName` parameter rather than `localhost` but still had no luck.

The error seems to refer to an error in the actual module itself rather than my code. Can anyone suggest where I am going wrong?

Environment

- Power BI Report Server version: 1.8.7450.37410 (May 2020)
- Instance name: PBIRS
- Report Manager URL: http://localhost/reports
- Service URL: http://localhost/reportserver
- ReportServer database is on a SQL Server 2016 instance (the database name is PowerBIReportServer)

**EDIT:**

Using the two answers so far, I have found the following:

```
Restore-RsEncryptionKey -ComputerName "localhost" -Password $encKeyPass -KeyPath $encKeyPath -ReportServerInstance PBIRS -ReportServerVersion SQLServer2016
```

Throws

```
Invalid namespace "root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ReportServer\RS_PBIRS\v13\Admin"
```

and changing the -ReportServerVersion:

```
Restore-RsEncryptionKey -ComputerName "localhost" -Password $encKeyPass -KeyPath $encKeyPath -ReportServerInstance PBIRS -ReportServerVersion SQLServer2017
```

Throws

```
Invalid namespace "root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ReportServer\RS_PBIRS\v14\Admin"
```

(note the difference in versions)

running

```
Get-WmiObject -Namespace "Root/Microsoft/SqlServer/ReportServer/RS_PBIRS" -Class __Namespace | Select-Object -Property Name | Sort Name
```

outputs:

```
Name
----
V15
```

which makes sense as to why the two different `-ReportServerVersion` arguments throw an error.

[this page](https://github.com/microsoft/ReportingServicesTools) suggests

```
+--------------------+---------+
| SQL Server Release | Version |
+--------------------+---------+
| SQL Server 2012    |      11 |
| SQL Server 2014    |      12 |
| SQL Server 2016    |      13 |
| SQL Server 2017    |      14 |
| SQL Server 2019    |      15 |
+--------------------+---------+
```

but changing `-ReportServerVersion` to  `SQLServer2019` returns:

```
Restore-RSEncryptionKey : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'ReportServerVersion'. Cannot convert value 
"SQLServer2019" to type "Microsoft.ReportingServicesTools.SqlServerVersion". Error: "Unable to match the identifier name 
SQLServer2019 to a valid enumerator name. Specify one of the following enumerator names and try again:
SQLServer2012, SQLServer2014, SQLServer2016, SQLServer2017, SQLServervNext"
At line:3 char:143
```

From here then I suppose the question is:

How do I get the module to run v15 OR how do I get version 13 of the module / namespace?

Comment: Did you try `-ReportServerVersion SQLServervNext`?

Comment: Thanks - it works!
The suggestion by Witt also worked. As you are both right but I have to pick one answer to award the bounty, I'm afraid I will have to award to Witt as his troubleshooting steps were a bit more detailed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error *is* being thrown from the module, but it appears to be as a result of the data we're putting *into* the module. Let's dive into the code to see what's happening.

I found the source code of the module [here](https://github.com/microsoft/ReportingServicesTools/blob/master/ReportingServicesTools/Functions/Utilities/New-RsConfigurationSettingObject.ps1). These lines towards the bottom (85 through 102) stuck out to me:

```bsh
    $getWmiObjectParameters = @{
        ErrorAction = "Stop"
        Namespace = "root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ReportServer\RS_$ReportServerInstance\v$($ReportServerVersion.Value__)\Admin"
        Class = "MSReportServer_ConfigurationSetting"
    }
    
    # code snipped

    $wmiObjects = Get-WmiObject @getWmiObjectParameters
```

Looking back at your error, the first line is noting "invalid namespace". If anything looks immediately off in `"root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ReportServer\RS_PBIRS\v13\Admin"` or your values for `$ReportServerInstance` or `$($ReportServerVersion.Value__)` then I'd change those.

If those look okay to you, I'd suggest you manually search through the available WMI namespaces on the target machine. First, we want to return all the child namespaces of root.

```bsh
PS C:\windows\system32> Get-WmiObject -Namespace "Root" -Class __Namespace | Select-Object -Property Name | Sort Name

Name
----
Appv
cimv2
Hardware
HyperVCluster
Microsoft
WMI
```

Now that we have those, we can continue searching down the path that the module is expecting. We know from the module code, it's expecting to hit "Microsoft" in the namespace/path next so add that to the namespace we're searching child namespaces for:

```bsh
PS C:\windows\system32> Get-WmiObject -Namespace "Root\Microsoft" -Class __Namespace | Select-Object -Property Name | Sort Name

Name
----
HomeNet
PolicyPlatform
protectionManagement
SecurityClient
Uev
Windows
```

I think if you continue down that line of logic, you'll run into the spot where the module is expecting a child WMI namespace, but the target machine lacks it.

Hope this was helpful and good luck!

#### ****Update:

To answer the new question *'How do I get the module to run v15 OR how do I get version 13 of the module / namespace?'*

The example use of the cmdlet shows use of the 2-digit report server version so I'd have you try this:

```bsh
Restore-RsEncryptionKey -ComputerName "localhost" -Password $encKeyPass -KeyPath $encKeyPath -ReportServerInstance PBIRS -ReportServerVersion '15'
```

If that returns the same error, try `Connect-RsReportServer`. Module documentation notes it will set/update the parameter `ReportServerVersion`

```
        .PARAMETER ReportServerVersion
            Specify the version of the SQL Server Reporting Services Instance.
            Use the "Connect-RsReportServer" function to set/update a default value.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This has unearthed some interesting information. Question now amended to reflect

Comment: @Searle1986 I've updated my answer to respond to your updated question. Let me know how it goes!

Comment: thanks! This works!
It also works with -ReportServerVersion SQLServervNext as suggested by Thomas.

Comment: Bounty awarded due to most in depth troubleshooting information of the two answers (Although the other was a comment on my question)

Answer (score 3):

To troubleshoot problems with the `-ReportServerVersion` parameter in the [`ReportingServicesTools`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ReportingServicesTools/) module, resulting in namespace errors, you can use the following three quick steps:

1. Determine the SQL server versions your server supports (replace `PBIRS` by your actual ReportServerInstance, if different):

   ```bsh
   Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ReportServer\RS_PBIRS" -Class __Namespace | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
   ```

   Example output:

   ```
   V15
   ```
2. Display the current version to name mappings in [`ReportingServicesTools`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ReportingServicesTools/):

   ```bsh
   [enum]::GetValues([Microsoft.ReportingServicesTools.SqlServerVersion]) | % {[PSCustomObject]@{Name = $_;Version = $_.value__}}
   ```

   Example output:

   ```
             Name Version
             ---- -------
    SQLServer2012      11
    SQLServer2014      12
    SQLServer2016      13
    SQLServer2017      14
   SQLServervNext      15
   ```
3. Map your supported server version to the corresponding name in the [`ReportingServicesTools`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ReportingServicesTools/) module and use this name to pass it to the `-ReportServerVersion` parameter or pass the integer directly (after stripping the `v`).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately it didn't work however I have now updated the question with some further info

Comment: I updated my answer to a quick TSHOOT guide. Might be a good summary for future readers.